# Application Insights - View SQL Query

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a .NET 4.6.1 setup. I am able to see SQL show up as a dependency but I'd like to view the commands it's executing to this way we can take a look at what's taking the most time. Right now in the command section, it's just showing the FQDN for the sql server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what kind of app you have and where it is deployed, but the full instructions are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies

> ## Set up dependency monitoring
>
> Partial dependency information is
>   collected automatically by the Application Insights SDK.
>
> To get
>   complete data, install the appropriate agent for the host server.
>
> - IIS Server -  Either install Status Monitor on your server or Upgrade your application to .NET framework 4.6 or later and install
>     the Application Insights SDK in your app.
> - Azure Web App -  In your web app control panel, open the Application Insights blade in your web app control panel and choose Install if
>     prompted.
> - Azure Cloud Service -    Use startup task or Install .NET framework 4.6+

Comment: this does not work. I have a .NET 4.6 POC project setup, I've deployed to an Azure App service as well and it's not recording SQL commands. I am on version 2.3.0 of Azure App Insights SDK.

Comment: and the place *you're deploying to* also is using .net 4.6?

Comment: and/or is that place also configured properly for status monitor to work?

Comment: John, I had the extension installed for the app service and it wasn't recording the sql, I decided to setup a new app service and install the extension, then deployed the app. Everything worked as expected. It seems there was something wrong with the extension on the first app service, after removing it and readding it all worked as expected. Sorry for the confusion. There was no warning or errors anywhere for me to figure it out. Took some trial and error. Thank you.

Comment: no problem.  status monitor injects AI as a clr profiler, there are other tools and monitoring solutions that could also have been doing the same and somehow unhooked it, or random other scenarios could have happen. glad you got it working!

Comment: @TheWebGuy - so you ended up needing *both* Status Monitor installed as well as the .NET 4.6 and SDK? The docs make it sound like it's either a) Status Monitor or b) .NET 4.6 and SDK.... However we have NET 4.6 and SDK and it's not logging the entire query.